# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'appendChild'); Persistent Error

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, dom, appendchild

My script tag is at the bottom of my body tag which is the main solution I have found on here. Is there any other reasons appendChild would be running into this error?

Html:

```
     <section class="section-2">
       <p class="about-me-text"></p>
     </section>
     <script src="rScript.js"></script>
   </body>
```

Javascript:

```
const aboutMeText = document.querySelector("about-me-text");
const aboutMeTextContent = 'I am a creative designer, who dabbles in both website 
creation & digital art design. Contact me to start a creative project or website 
today.'

Array.from(aboutMeTextContent).forEach(char => {
 const span = document.createElement("span");
 span.textContent = char;
 aboutMeText.appendChild(span);
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a "." to querySelector() when targeting a class name.

```js
const aboutMeText = document.querySelector(".about-me-text");
const aboutMeTextContent = `I am a creative designer, who dabbles in both website
  creation & digital art design. Contact me to start a creative project or website
  today.`

Array.from(aboutMeTextContent).forEach(char => {
  const span = document.createElement("span");
  span.textContent = char;
  aboutMeText.appendChild(span);
})
```

```html
<section class="section-2">
  <p class="about-me-text"></p>
</section>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I am still new to coding and don't yet have my eye trained to pick up on those small typos that will ruin everything.

Comment: Happy to help. No worries, typos will stump even the most experienced. We all need a fresh pair of eyes now and then. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

When using `querySelector`, you have to clarify which element are you selecting, for example, in your problem as you're selecting a class, you have to put a `.` in the start of `about-me-text`. For a ID, you'll add a `#` at the start, etc.

```js
const aboutMeText = document.querySelector(".about-me-text");
const aboutMeTextContent = 'I am a creative designer, who dabbles in both website creation & digital art design. Contact me to start a creative project or website today.'

Array.from(aboutMeTextContent).forEach(char => {
 const span = document.createElement("span");
 span.textContent = char;
 aboutMeText.appendChild(span);
})
```

```html
<section class="section-2">
       <p class="about-me-text"></p>
     </section>
     <script src="rScript.js"></script>
   </body>
```